# Is / always the path of the system drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I need to know which drive is the System drive.

Is it safe to assume that `/` is always the system drive ? Or in some situation (for example booting from a FW drive) `/` is not the drive were the system is. thanks.

Comment: Off topic, go to stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah ... the same post was closed/deleted there. And since it's a OS X global question ... It might have more its place here.

Comment: Did they give a reason? Anyways, `/` is by definition the path of the drive from which you booted.

Comment: No the post was just deleted right after I got closed ... But thx for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is yes, although it depends a bit on exactly what you mean by "system drive". A few versions ago, Apple introduced what they call "Boot≠Root"; I can't find much documentation on it, but the basic idea is that OS X can load the booter file from one volume, then use a different volume as the operating system root.

For instance, when your startup volume is encrypted with FileVault 2, it actually loads the booter from a different volume (the hidden "Recovery HD" volume); the booter decrypts the startup volume, and then loads the operating system from the encrypted volume.

The rule is that / will always refer to the volume you are *running the operating system from*, just not necessarily the one that the boot process started from. This applies whether you're starting from an internal disk, FireWire disk, USB disk, NetBoot disk image, disk image,... whatever.